# I moved child widget by paintChild offset, but the click event on child is still on the original position

Tags: flutter

the paint code:

```
void Paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    context.paintChild(child, offset + _offset);
}
```

and, the click event on the child:

```
Container(
    width: _buttonWidth,
    child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      onButtonPressed();
    },
    color: buttonColor,
    child: Text(
      "button",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
    )),
)
```

what i want is that the click event can follow the moved child. So, who can help me about this question?

Comment: Please add more context, because we don't know for example if you are creating your own `RenderBox`or `RenderSliver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your own widget and you customize your widget's children's paint, you may have to override the `hitTestChildren` as well.

If you you are creating your own `RenderBox`, the `hitTestChildren` may look like this:

```
@override
bool hitTestChildren(HitTestResult result, { Offset position }) {
  if (child != null) {
    return child.hitTest(result, position: position - _offset);
  }
  return false;
}
```